# Using git merge-base to see which of the commits is newer

Tags: git

Here is something like my scenario. I have two developers working on two different machines but on a same branch. At some point, I want to know which one of their commits is latest.

```
On branch A -> developer 1 has -> C1 -> C2 ->C3
On branch A -> developer 2 has -> C1 -> C2 ->C4
```

Commit C4 was made after commit C3, but the dev2 doesn't have the commit C3.

```
git merge-base C3 HEAD on dev2's machine
```

It should say that c3 is the common ancestor. Can I use this to conclude that C4(current HEAD) is the latest?

Thanks for looking.

Comment: You cannot call `merge-base C3 HEAD` if the commit is missing on the local machine. And `C3` won't be the common ancestor, `C2` is. How do you define _latest_? Timestamp, content? Because both commits (C3, C4) are essentially equally "old" (both have a distance of 1 to commit C2)

Comment: I see. What if when the user makes commit C3 or C4, he pushes it to remote? And when doing this check on dev2's machine, if I do a fetch and then run the above command. Will it work? Sorry. I am a totally lost newbie. If you can suggest a solution on how to do this it would be helpful.

Comment: I don't know which problem you are trying to solve? Whoever fetches the changes from the remote has to merge (or rebase) his changes with the remote changes. You will get a new merge commit (no additional commit when rebasing) which has the changes from both developers. [Most git tutorials should have this covered](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches).

Comment: Sorry. What I am trying to tell is which of the commits is latest by timestamp. Assuming when commits C3 and C4 are made, they are merged with the remote but for my test, I only have c3 and c4 not the remote new merge commit ids.

Comment: `git show --pretty=medium` will show you the author timestamp of the commit (as will `git log` and some other commands). I don't understand what exactly you expect from this information?

Comment: So if developer 1's clock is wrong, he can be the newest (or not the newest) even if his commit was earlier (or later)?

Comment: That shouldnt be correct. Which is why I am bummed that its not based on timestamp. What I was thinking is more like a branch gets commits C1, C2, C3 and C4 in this order. Coming from two different developers, but the same branch. When I look, I want to be able to tell that c4 was the last commit in that branch.

Comment: If Dev2 does a fetch before running this check, will git merge-base c3 head work? After a fetch, does dev2 git have idea of what c3 is?

Comment: @user3606175: you can not tell which of the commits `C3` or `C4` is "older" relative to each other, both come directly after `C2`, that's all you know. Also, I don't think there's any benefit in knowing which of the commits was made at a later point in time (because they are unrelated). `git merge-base C3 C4` (C4=HEAD) will always give you `C2` as merge-base. After a fetch, dev2 will know about `C3` (again, all git tutorials have this covered. Please make sure you have a basic understanding of how changes propagate through Git repositories). Still, what do you want to do with that information…

Comment: … about knowing which commit was made at a later point in time? Do you also have to consider different timezones? Why do you want to know which commit was made later? What do you want with that commit? (Or what don't you want to do with the other commit?). Please state a use-case (I fear we have an XY-problem)

Comment: More specifically, `C4` was in fact **not** made after `C3` … it was only made after `C2`.

Comment: Sorry about all the confusion. And I want to first thankyou for trying to resolve this for me. I appreciate it a it. I have started to realize that merge-base is not what I want. You are right. C2 will be the common ancestor.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60668/discussion-between-knittl-and-user3606175).

Comment: @user3606175: are you still there? I should find a little bit of time today